# Eclipse plug-in: Specifying the output folder for an included file

Tags: eclipse, plugins, export

I'm trying to export a plug-in into a jar. In this jar file I would like to include an extra file placed in the bin\com.example.myapp. This file is generated during compilation, but it's not copied automatically into the jar file when exporting the plug-in.
To include the file I selected the file in the Build Configuration tab for plugin.xml file. Thus, the following build.properties is created:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               bin/com/example/myapp/myfile.bin
jre.compilation.profile = JavaSE-1.7
```

This works partially, because even though myfile.bin is included into the exported jar file, it is placed in "bin/com/example/myapp/myfile.bin" whereas I would like to be placed as "com/example/myapp/myfile.bin", without the initial "bin" folder. Is there a way to achieve that result?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the bin output folder but I think it will apply to ALL files, not just one :

```
Right click on your project and select Properties. And then click on Java Build Path. On the right side you can see the tabs Source, Projects, Libraries,...

Click on Source. Check the Default output folder:. There you can browse and select the different folder you want.
```